# Why is Stellaris - Galaxy Edition cheaper than Nova Edition?

Tags: steam, stellaris

It's obvious that the Galaxy Edition contains more stuff than the Nova Edition.

[image]

[image]

Also, the price of [Stellaris: Nova Edition Upgrade Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/616190/Stellaris_Nova_Edition_Upgrade_Pack/) is nearly one-third of [Stellaris: Galaxy Edition Upgrade](http://Packhttp://store.steampowered.com/app/616191/).

[image]

However, strangely, Stellaris: Galaxy Edition merely costs ¥ 91, whereas Stellaris: Nova Edition costs ¥ 103.

[image]

Is it a mistake? If so, can we take advantage of it? *evil chuckle*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in May, Paradox, the developer and publisher of Stellaris, adjusted the price of many products upwards to adjust for consumer wage increases and to bring prices across multiple regions more in line with one another. You can clearly see this on the price graphs for the base, Nova and Galaxy packages:

https://steamdb.info/app/281990/
https://steamdb.info/sub/99328/
https://steamdb.info/sub/100387/

As you can see, both the base and Nova package had the price increased in pretty much every currency apart from EUR, GBP and USD around the 23rd of May 2017. However, the Galaxy package has not been adjusted in this way for some reason. Because of this, in all currencies besides the 3 above, the Galaxy package is actually cheaper than the Nova package, because it never had the original price hike.

Paradox has already stated that they will adjust the prices for the games back to their original pre-increase levels when the Steam Sales have ended, because they can't do it in the middle of the Steam sale.